If $M\in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb Z)$ has no eigenvalue other than $1$, does this mean that it has an eigenvector in $\mathbb{Z}^n$?
I can prove that this true for $n=2$, as follows: If $M$ has $1$ as its only eigenvalue, then either it is $I$ (in which case the result is trivial) or it is similar to $
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$, which implies that it must have the form $$
M = \begin{bmatrix}1+dc&d^2\\ -c^2 & 1-dc\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some $d,c\in \mathbb{C}$. Since $M\in\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ it must also be the case that $d^2,c^2,dc$ are integers. Then we have that $v=\begin{bmatrix}-d^2\\ dc\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $$
Mv = \begin{bmatrix}1+dc&d^2\\ -c^2 & 1-dc\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-d^2\\ dc\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-d^2-d^3c+d^3c\\d^2c^2+dc-d^2c^2\end{bmatrix} = v
$$
so $v$ is an eigenvector in $\mathbb{Z}^2$.
I am wondering whether the same holds in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for all $n$. Given $M\in\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $1$ is the only complex eigenvalue of $M$, does it necessarily follow that there exists $v\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $Mv=v$?

If I'm not mistaken, the hypothesis that all the eigenvalues are $1$ is overly strong. I think a single eigenvalue being equal to $1$ is good enough; that is, as long as $\det(M - \operatorname{id}_n) = 0$.
More generally, the following statement is true: if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with integer entries with $\det A = 0$, then there is a nonzero vector $v \in \mathbb Z^n$ such that $A v = 0$. The proof is to work over the field of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$ (rather than $\mathbb C$), which promises you there's a valid $0 \neq v \in \mathbb Q^n$, then scale by the least common multiples of all the denominators (i.e. you have $n v \in \mathbb Z^n$ for some big integer $n$).
To apply to your problem, set $A = M - \operatorname{id}_n$.
The short lesson is that linear algebra just works well over any field, so you don't need to work in the unnecessarily large field $\mathbb C$; if you already have integer entries, just work over $\mathbb Q$ instead. The field extension to something like $\mathbb C$ is useful in a situation where e.g. you want to get the complex roots of the characteristic polynomial; but in this case the root is promised to be $1$ anyway.

So in general it is true that over a field $K$, if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with entries in $K$ and determinant $0$, it has a nontrivial nullspace in $K^n$? That makes sense, I guess it follows immediately from the rank-nullity theorem. Thanks :)

Yep, that's correct!

In fact, if $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ is an eigenvalue of $M \in GL_n(\mathbb{Q})$, then $M$ has an eigenvector in $\mathbb{Z}^n$. For let $v \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ be an eigenvector. Let $D$ be a common denominator of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$. Then $Dv \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ is an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue as $v$.
